# How to use common sqlite database for multiple applications on a mobile?

Tags: android, ios, database, windows-phone

I want to create multiple applications on Android which will use same database. Is it possible? and How we can achieve it.

With same logic I also want to create same applications for Windows and iOS, Is it possible with Windows Phone and iOS too?

Have a nice day!

Regards,
Dinesh

Comment: Not possible in Windows Phone world as each application run with own **isolated** storage.

Comment: @Adarsha, thanks for your reply. Can you please share any link for confirmation?

Comment: on a serious note, **you** need to do that research. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff402541(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: Common sqlite means a single SQLITE for 3 platforms windows, ios and windows ?? If your requirement is 3 different sqlite files for different platform, then answer is yes you can. All you need to do is creating sqlite with the same structures and tables.